# Build Flavours for Java project

Tags: java, gradle

Build Flavours are commonly used in Android applications through the android gradle plugin. This allows a project to have a directory structure

```
src
  - main
    - com.stack.A.java
  - debug
    - com.stack.B.java
  - release
    - com.stack.B.java
```

This will only compile the correct `B.java` depending  on the release type that has been selected.

Is there a way to mirror this functionality without using the android gradle plugin and just using the java plugin?

Answer (score 5):

It is called sourceSet in Java plugin, see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html

`main` and `test` sourceSets are created automatically, to add more sourceSets you can do something like below. Basically both releases and debug also uses codes in main

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {
    release {
        java {
            srcDirs 'src/main/java', 'src/release/java'
        }
    }

    debug {
        java {
            srcDirs 'src/main/java', 'src/debug/java'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've written a plugin to achieve this. Eg

```
apply plugin: 'com.lazan.javaflavours'
javaFlavours {
    flavours = ['free', 'paid']
}
```

Then sources in `src/free/java` and `src/paid/java` and resources in `src/free/resources` and `src/paid/resources`

Project on github: https://github.com/uklance/gradle-java-flavours

Comment: Looks very promising! But how to choose in IntelliJ IDEA, which flavour I want to use (e. g. which `someFlavourCompile` should be available in the project)?

Comment: Tasks for all flavours will be listed in IDEA. If you want to limit the flavours I guess you could use some custom property to define the flavour list which you edit